# Gitlab Runner Docker container can't connect to Prometheus

Tags: docker, gitlab, prometheus, docker-swarm, gitlab-ci-runner

If I set listen address in config.toml:

```
listen_address = "<ip address of gitlab server>:9090"
```

I get the error message when I try to bring it up with just compose, outside of docker swarm.

```
gitlab-runner_1  | FATAL: Failed to create listener for metrics server \
  builds=0 error=listen tcp <ip address of gitlab server>:9090: bind: \
  cannot assign requested address
```

I've tried everything I can think of but if I comment out that line it works fine so I'm not sure what the problem could be.

The port is listening:

```
tcp        0      0 < ip address of gitlab server>:9090    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

The Docker logs are also confusing:

```
May 08 13:14:07 <hostname> dockerd[23555]: time="2020-05-08T18:14:07.136612480Z" 
\ level=error msg="fatal task error" \
error="No such image:< registry_hostname>:5005/containers/gitlab-runner:latest" \
module=node/agent/taskmanager node.id=t89xq3b5gqmd14uusi0hl8m2t \
service.id=i5syamim547sw4bpl43heia6p task.id=qo1jb5czjkx92xynb71ujn2aw
```

Though the image clearly did pull down and is attempting to run but failing over and over, as shown by `watch -n1 'docker ps'` - every so often it will start and then crash and repeat.

The logs also have:

```
May 08 13:14:07 <hostname> dockerd[23555]: time="2020-05-08T18:14:07.189471594Z" \
level=info msg="initialized VXLAN UDP port to 4789 " \
May 08 13:14:08 <hostnanme> dockerd[23555]: time="2020-05-08T18:14:08.924624811Z" \
level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) \
deleting object [endpoint k65gt23bo5wydunh1j39ge7t3 \
906e54b5e63372d95294e4d35d14d55bfd6cc06a987ea667f7d0a38b17e99ddd], retrying...."
```

Which doesn't mean a lot to me but looks important.

Comment: Are you running GitLab Runner in a Docker container (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html) ?  Did you do anything to add Prometheus?  (I'm trying to figure out how to get to this point, so I can try to replicate your issue.)

Comment: I have Gitlab CE Omnibus installed (12.09). I have Docker 19.03 installed (latest) This is on RHEL 7.7.  Docker is in swarm mode and is the swarm leader.  I am running gitlab runner in a docker container gitlab/gitlab-runner. config.toml is mounted as a volume. SSL certificate is mounted as a volume and the SSL certificate key is mounted as a secret .